# Power BI >> Images not coming up on app

Tags: powerbi

I have a power BI dashboard connecting to SSAS Data Model ( via Live Connection)
We have a requirement to display the images on Power BI App. 
We have a dimension table having Account Name and every account name will have an image/logo.
Initially – we built a solution to store the logos in Sharepoint and use that Image URL in our SSAS Data Model and we made sure that every user who wanted to view the image/logo in dashboard has access to Sharepoint as well.

This solution was working for few people and few folks were seeing the images being broken.

We worked with Microsoft team and we were told that images display works only – when the SharePoint location is opened for all (Anonymous authentication  ) .

Unfortunately – we are not supposed to open the Sharepoint to anonymous authentication. So we tried below things

•   We opened Sharepoint location to Everyone ( i.e, everyone in our organization )  - Didnt work 
•   We tried performing the same via ( File share available on Power BI workspace ) - Didnt work
•   We also explored giving BLOB Storage with anonymous – but again , we are restricted to open up this data in anonymous mode. Hence BLOB option is also ruled out

So – now , I am looking for a option – that can help my users to view the images on Power BI app.

Btw – we are on Power BI Premium . Is there anything more Premium offers in resolving this issue ?

> > Below is the screen shot from Power BI app ( where a restricted logo is shown and not the actual logo) . We also made the same user directly access the Sharepoint URL – where the image is stored and that is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar issue which being cannot upload images to the public domain as you explained in the problem. What I did was upload all the files into SharePoint with an ID of the accounts and get those into a table in power bi. Convert those images into base 64 and showed them.

Please follow these steps to get images into base64 and import them into PBI. I hope the image is not too big (below 32 KB) otherwise this solution is not good

[link](https://prologika.com/showing-database-images-in-power-bi-and-tabular/)